# Running many consecutive exes with wine, fast

Tags: wine

Starting a windows exe with wine is slow, because the wine should be initialized first which is slow (mapping and linking a lot of dlls, analyzing config files, mapping resources, etc).

I think if wine could run like a daemon which could give its context to a newly started exe, it could significantly fasten the exe startup time. Although transfering some resources (file descriptors, mappings) between processes isn't easy and isn't always posix-standard, in newer Linux kernels it is already possible.

As I know, there is a wineserver in the wine, but unfortunately I didn't find too much from it in the Google.

Does some similar already exist? Or can it be done with the current wineserver, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current wineserver (as of 2017) already does that. At least that is what I understood from this part of the man page of wineserver:

```
   -p[n], --persistent[=n]
          Specify the wineserver persistence delay,  i.e.  the  amount  of
          time that the server will keep running when all client processes
          have terminated. This avoids  the  cost  of  shutting  down  and
          starting  again  when programs are launched in quick succession.
          The timeout n is in seconds, the default value is 3 seconds.  If
          n is not specified, the server stays around forever.
```

As far as I understand wineserver will start with the first invocation of wine. After wine quits the wineserver will stick around for 3 seconds. If there is a second wine invocation during the 3 seconds then the existing wineserver will be reused.